# JQuery.cookies setting a key value pair

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to use the JQuery cookies library http://code.google.com/p/cookies/ But am not able to set key value pairs within the cookie. I can't see how in the documentation, does anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `$.cookies.set("myCookie", "value")`?

Comment: ^^ That won't set a key value pair which is what I need. Though yes that does work and will set the value to string 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the JSON example in the link you referenced.

```
//JSON 
var jimData = {id: 1, name: 'jim'}; 
$.cookies.set( 'userdata', jimData ); //A cookie by the name 'userdata' now exists with a serialized copy of jimData 

var userData = $.cookies.get( 'userdata' ); //A variable named 'userData' now holds the unserialized object--should be identical to the variable 'jimData'
```

So, `userData` should now have properties `id` with value `1` and `name` with value `'jim'`.

Comment: I saw that but will I be able to retrieve the object as a key value pair from c#?

Comment: I would rather not have to decode a JSON object in c# as this does not seem straightforward

Comment: Have you looked at the DataContractJsonSerializer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx?  If you had a class with the correct properties onto which the cookie would map the code should be trivial.

Comment: That looks cool do you know which .net library this belong to?
JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject

Comment: Are you thinking of JSON.Net: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx?  The DataContractJsonSerializer is in System.Runtime.Serialization.  I haven't used JSON.Net.